# get data from db and display in codeigniter and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

in my controller :

```
public function viewOrders() {
        $territoryId = $this->input->post('tid');
        $dateStart = $this->input->post('sdate');
        $dateEnd = $this->input->post('edate');

        $data = array(
            'TERRITORY_ID' => $territoryId,
            'ORDER_DATE' => $dateStart,
            'EXP_COLL_DATE' => $dateEnd
        );

        $this->order->viewOrder($data);
    }
```

in my model :

```
public function viewOrder($data) {
        return $this->db->select('ORDER_ID,ORDER_DATE,EXP_COLL_DATE,STATUS')
                        ->from('ORDER_HEADER')
                        ->join('ORDER_DETAILS', 'ORDER_HEADER.TERRITORY_ID=ORDER_DETAILS.TERRITORY_ID', 'INNER')
                        ->where($data);

    }
```

in footer  (view) :

```
function viewOrders() {
        var dateStart = $('#dateStart').val();
        var dateEnd = $('#dateEnd').val();
        var territories = $('#territory').val();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/Orders/viewOrders", {tid: territories, sdate: dateStart, edate: dateEnd}).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);

        });
    }
```

Comment: i want to display my data but i get only a empty alert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... whats your question? Any errors you get?

Comment: no i didnt get any error i want to display my data which are in database in a html table

Answer (score 0):

You missed - $query = $this->db->get();
get array here $data = $query->result_array();

and return $data

Comment: it gives an error    Call to undefined method CI_DB_oci8_driver::result_array()

Comment: just call $query->result() check if it returns array

Comment: it return only empty

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); try this sql on database [phpmyadmin]